# Wireless isn't working on Lenovo T400

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade, lenovo

This problem started after upgrading to 12.04, an my system is 'up2date'

Have tried most of the solution-proposals found on the net.

**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LF Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10bf] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:20ee]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1211]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlagn
```

**iwconfig**

```
>lo        no wireless extensions.

>eth0      no wireless extensions.

>wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off

          Encryption key:off

          Power Management:off
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

> *-network
>   
> description: Ethernet interface
>   
> product: 82567LF Gigabit Network Connection
>   
> vendor: Intel Corporation
>   
> physical id: 19
>   
> bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
>   
> logical name: eth0
>   
> version: 03
>   
> serial: 00:22:68:1a:c4:75
>   
> size: 100Mbit/s
>   
> capacity: 1Gbit/s
>   
> width: 32 bits
>   
> clock: 33MHz
>   
> capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
>   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.0.2-k2 duplex=full firmware=1.8-3 ip=192.168.2.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
>   resources: irq:29 memory:fc000000-fc01ffff memory:fc024000-fc024fff ioport:1820(size=32)
>   
> *-network DISABLED
>   description: Wireless interface
>   product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
>   vendor: Intel Corporation
>   physical id: 0
>   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>   logical name: wlan0
>   version: 00
>   serial: 00:26:c6:6c:2d:24
>   width: 64 bits
>   clock: 33MHz
>   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
>   resources: irq:30 memory:f4300000-f4301fff

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
network DISABLED
```

Indicates your wireless radio killswitch is still active.

Run

```
sudo rfkill list
```

to see what the current state is. "Soft blocked" can be unblocked using a command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

"Hard blocked" means you'll have to find the switch on your notebook to unlock it.